# Cannot run ALS.train, error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run [ALS of PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html). I copied & pasted the sample code provided in the link. However, the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` occurs at the line:

`model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)`

May I ask what possible problems do I need to investigate here?

My Spark version is 2.2.1, my Java version is 9.0.4. However, I am not sure if Spark is using the right version of Java although I set the environment path and the command "java -version" does return "9.0.4".

Error:

[image]

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.pythonToJava. :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:443)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40) at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103) at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
>   at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381) at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:794)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:793)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:793) at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDeBase.pythonToJava(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1349)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.pythonToJava(PythonMLLibAPI.scala)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280) at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214) at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. Spark 2.2.1 does not go with Java 9.0.4. Maybe I have misunderstood the part "Java 8+" of the tutorial.

If anyone meets the same error as me, just go for Java 1.8.0!